# Is it possible to specify send and receive ports for scapy sendp

Tags: scapy

I want to send via scapy on one interface and listen on another. Instead of writing two functions, I'm curious if the existing "Send and Receive" function of Scapy "srp" supports specifying an "ingress" and "egress" port

For example, I'm sending on "Eth4" now, and I wish to listen to "Eth5", right now it is sending and listening on the same port

```
h=srp(Ether()/IP()/TCP(sport=80,dport=8080),iface="eth4")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface you specify in Scapy via `srp()` is the one interface it will listen on for sending and receiving.

Both the `sendp` and `sniff` functions have the `inter`face option. Send your packet on your chosen interface with `sendp` and listen for it on your ingress interface with `sniff`.